# How to launch nvim in current terminal and show all current contents in it(including color)?

Tags: terminal, neovim

For Kitty terminal there is a `scrollback_pager` feature, here is a minimal configuration:

`scrollback_pager bash -c "nvim 64<&0 0</dev/null -c 'terminal sed </dev/fd/64 -e \"\" '"`

It redirects terminal contents to `/dev/fd/64` and then redirects that to nvim's terminal through `sed`. It works, but now I switched to Wezterm, it doesn't have this feature, so I tried the command directly in terminal:

`bash -c "nvim 64<&0 0</dev/null -c 'terminal sed </dev/fd/64 -e \"\" '"`

It doesn't work, even for Kitty.

How to do that directly in terminal?

Please note I'd prefer:

1. NOT generating any temporary file
2. NOT using nvim's plugin like "AnsiEsc" to show the ansi color, because that uses nvim's color scheme than terminal's.
3. NOT using system clipboard because it may contain useful stuff.